# How to update certain value in database and set the relation

Tags: php, sql, laravel

The website I'm trying to make is a reservation and booking website. I have 3 tables that i use for the reservation process.

**available_rooms** table

```
id  room_number  room_type  status
 1      1        Standard      1
 2      2        Standard      1
```

**reservation** table

```
id checkindate checkoutdate room_type status
1  12/12/2018  12/13/2018    Standard  unpaid
```

**clients** table

```
id  firstName lastName  phoneNumber  emailAdress
 1  test      test       999999       admin@admin.com
```

What i want to happen is after the client entered all the necessary information in the booking request for it will then be saved in this 3 separate tables. That is all working fine except that the **available_rooms** table is not updating the status to "0"("1" for available and "0" for not available). I'm currently using this code to try to update it but it's not working.

```
  $roomavailability = availableRoom::where('room_type', $request->session()->get('room_type'))
    ->update(['status' => 0]);
```

And I think my table structure is lacking relation. I'm new with laravel and sql, My question is this approach about a booking system correct? or am I missing something? I know I need a relation for the client and reservation table but I dont know where to put it.

Answer (score 0):

Is status listed in your

```
protected $fillable
```

on the availableRoom model?

Or is that even a model? Normally you would have a Room Model that would have the availability set as a property on it.

Comment: Yes, I have that room model with protected  $fillable=['room_number','room_type','status']; 
What do you mean about setting the property? can you give me an example?

Comment: Property of the model would be the same as the columns on the table. Youd access it via $model->property.

Comment: If this solved you or got you there, can you accept the answer?